# how can i find the public IP address (external) using UbuntuCore? not curl/telnet/wget/dig maybe netcat?

Tags: pi-3, networking, snappy

I have researched and found dozens of ways to determine the public IP on a standard Rasbian or UbuntuMate Distro. Because I am working in UbuntuCore I do not have access to any thing that I cannot install through the snap package installer. (background) I am creating a networked surveillance system for a class project but have some limitations due to the high security of the school/test network. I've narrowed my search to a package/tool to perform http get request though I'm not sure I'm looking in the correct direction

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Feel free to take the tour at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour that will help you get the most from this site.   Have you tried just using your web browser?  Many sites will feed it back to you like GRC's Shields-Up and http://bearsmyip.com/

Answer (score 2):

After a very specific search **(netcat what is my ip)** I found this  [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253237/get-my-public-ip-using-netcat). My solution was the second answer: `echo 'GET /' | nc icanhazip.com 80` worked and gave me exactly what I was looking for... Hope someone else finds this useful!

Comment: The command does not work for me on `Raspbian 2018-03-13`. I get the error message `usage: nc [...]`.

Comment: Hey sorry about that. Its not a version issue I forgot to include the **port number** in the original post is all. Thanks this was helpful